# C# TCP/IP Server Response Text

Tags: c#, client, tcp

I'm writing a bit of software to communicate to a laser marker which connects over TCP/IP. I am using socket test to simulate this machine.

I am expecting to receive a particular set of responses from the machine which I have put into my code:

```
public static bool CheckConnection(string com, string server, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up TCP/IP");
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


            Byte[] Data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(com);
            stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", com);

            Data = new Byte[256];
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(Data, 0, Data.Length);
            string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", response);
            if (response != "VS 1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Test failed! Invalid response.");
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Test Successful!");
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception: {0}", e);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

the line `string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data, 0, bytes);` works but it returns '"VS 1\r\n"' causing the 'if' statement to evaluate to false.

Is there a way to return just the typed information from the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just trim that:

```
string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data, 0, bytes).Trim();
```